# Explanation of output in OPLS-DA

Tags: regression, clustering, partial-least-squares

I am dealing with metabolomics data, and using OPLS-DA to determine if 2+ groups cluster.  I've used the `ropls` package in R to create the following image.  This is real data, but just a practice run, as I know that this variable (Case/Control) should create 2 clusters.

[image: Sample OPLS-DA]

I'm trying to wrap my head around what I'm seeing, to understand the major points.  I've read through the package documentation and some papers on OPLS-DA.  But I'm not quite there.

*Questions*

1. Can someone explain R2Y and Q2Y?  My understanding right now is just that they're quality metrics, but that's about it.
2. Is there a significance score in the plot that I don't recognize?
3. Can you explain what the (7%) under the fourth plot is?
4. What are the most important a) significance and b) quality metrics for me to look at?